# Messaging Extension for Microsoft Teams doesn't display multiple parameter list for search

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use a Teams messaging extension to conduct a search using more than one field. As per the [MS Teams docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/search-extensions), it should be possible to specify multiple parameters for a messaging extension of type "query".

> For search based messaging extension set the type parameter to query.
>   Below is an example of a manifest with a single search command. A
>   single messaging extension can have up to 10 different commands
>   associated with it. This can include both multiple search and multiple
>   Action-based commands.

However, from what I can see multiple parameters only work for action types, not queries. I only see a single textbox for search whereas my manifest specifies multiple fields.

[image]

The following is an excerpt from the manifest.

```
"composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "[omitted]",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "search",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "search",
                    "description": "search",
                    "initialRun": false,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "compose",
                        "message"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "hello",
                            "title": "hello",
                            "description": "hello",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "test",
                            "title": "test",
                            "description": "test",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "addTodo",
                    "type": "action",
                    "title": "Create To Do",
                    "description": "Create a To Do item",
                    "initialRun": false,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": [
                        "commandBox",
                        "message",
                        "compose"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "Name",
                            "title": "Title",
                            "description": "To Do Title",
                            "inputType": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Description",
                            "title": "Description",
                            "description": "Description of the task",
                            "inputType": "textarea"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Date",
                            "title": "Date",
                            "description": "Due date for the task",
                            "inputType": "date"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out if this is at all possible. If not, are there any alternatives? My use case involves a user conduct a private search (i.e. the individual with whom they're chatting are unable to view the search result/query) and select an appropriate result from the list and send to another individual via chat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to specify multiple search commands, not multiple parameters (with one parameter per search command). Also note that you can't actually trigger a search-based command from an message, so you should only include the compose and commandBox scopes for them.

You can see what this will look like in the GitHub app for Teams:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that equate to independent search queries instead of a single query with multiple inputs? I'm looking to achieve the latter. Even so, I tried your suggestion as well. I still only see one field in the messaging extension window. However, I do see an additional blank space between the first field and the "Unable to reach app..." message (space enough for a new line to fit). It seems that perhaps there's a bug?

Comment: I was able to get to this point now. I believe removing the command associated with the "action" type allowed the multiple search commands to show. Is there no way to have multiple search boxes provide filter inputs for a single query?

Comment: The action command allows for multiple filter inputs but are wired to only return a single result whereas the query command allows a single filter input but returns a list. Isn't there any way to mix the two together in some way?

Comment: The closest you could probably come would be to use an action command to display the search form, then on submit of that form return another task module with an adaptive card that contains the list of responses. Alternatively, you could use a web view to populate your task module form which would give you flexibility to do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately both these options don't work for mobile at this time. Still accepting this as the answer as this is the closest that's achievable at this time. Thanks for your help!